# Python 3 RAW Byte String

Tags: python-3.x, string, format, shellcode, radare2

I want to know how to format a string as raw bytes in python3 just like it was in python2.

To clarify my Question, I have to following shellcode:

```
x = b"\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x90\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x62\x61\x73\x68\x68\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x68\x2f\x2f\x2f\x2f\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
```

and I want to pass this code to radare2 in python.

```
r.cmd("doo %s"%x)
```

Now is there a way that python passes my code as "real" bytes not as Unicode? I know it is possible to print it with

```
 sys.stdout.buffer.write(x)
```

but I want to pass it to the programm. Right now I am getting c290 not just 90. [Why is the output of print in python2 and python3 different with the same string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42884251/why-is-the-output-of-print-in-python2-and-python3-different-with-the-same-string) has already explained this behavior but it does not give a solution for my problem

Thank you

Comment: Hey Benedict, checkout my answer to a similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/59649426/12378826
The OP in that case asking about hex input, but you should consider using the `-e` flag with your `doo` command and using a hex string with additional escape characters instead of raw bytes.